# Washing Machine door locking/lights working, but no power to solenoid or motor

Tags: repair, washing-machine

My machine is turning on with the led's lighting, allowing me to select and start a program, doors locking and then the counter starts to countdown as normal. But nothing else happens, no water and no motor. I have tried spin modes etc, but they are all the same.

I have checked that the solenoids work when powered from an external source, But they are not receiving power from the control unit.
There is still meat on the motor bushes and the drum spins freely.

This is my first time looking at fixing a washing machine so I don't really know what else I can check, If there are fusees or other safety 'trips' etc? That said, I would have thought that if that was the issue there would be an Error message showing?

is there maybe a relay I can replace? or..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ash

Machine: Electrolux / Zanussi ZWF12280W

EDIT: inspired by jwh20's comment bellow, I took a closer look at the control board. I think it might be something to do with the 'chard' section.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the controller is failed.  Unfortunately there is not a lot to do but get another one and swap it out.

Comment: Is that because if the solanoid's are not getting power, that comes straight from the board. It must be that which is faulty. If there was something else wrong with it (a pressure pump for example) it would be showing an error?

Comment: Electrolux wants 180 quid for the board. That's not happening.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Often these machines have service modes which let you turn on/off any function in the machine; you'll need the service manual to figure that out.  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Thanks, I can find a User Manual but not a proper Service Manual.

Comment: be very careful when working on the board ... most likely, it has line voltage everywhere ... even low voltage parts could be hot .... a 5 V component could easily be using 235 V for ground and 240 V as the 5 V supply

Comment: That is definitely worth saying for anyone reading this. I am used to working with amplifier’s and similar high voltage equipment and take suitable care.

Comment: Well clearly you have found a problem.  That MAY BE repairable if you can ID and source the parts but you'll want to investigate WHY that happened to begin with.  Good luck!